# Failed to start Switcheroo Control Proxy service

Tags: linux

while installing Linux I got this message `[FAILED] Failed to start Switcheroo Control Proxy service.  See 'systemctl status switcheroo-control.service' for details.`

But fortunately it let me to log in without any problem, but I was a bit worried about that message, so I tried to run that command in terminal and got this:

```
● switcheroo-control.service - Switcheroo Control Proxy service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/switcheroo-control.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) 
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-06-27 14:41:18 +04; 2min 47s ago
  Process: 902 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/switcheroo-control (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 902 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

  Jun 27 14:41:18 mydesktop systemd[1]: Starting Switcheroo Control Proxy service...
  Jun 27 14:41:18 mydesktop switcheroo-cont[902]: switcheroo-control could not query vga_switcheroo status: Operation not permitted
  Jun 27 14:41:18 mydesktop systemd[1]: switcheroo-control.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
  Jun 27 14:41:18 mydesktop systemd[1]: switcheroo-control.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
  Jun 27 14:41:18 mydesktop systemd[1]: Failed to start Switcheroo Control Proxy service.
```

CPU: Intel Core i7 7500U 2.7Ghz, GPU: Intel HD 620 and Nvidia 940MX,

Is this a serious problem? and can you tell me how to fix it? thanks.

Comment: You'll have to disable secure boot in your BIOS boot options. It'll boot up then :))